# Equivalents for "She's got a lovely singing voice"

Tags: phrase-requests

> *She's got a lovely singing voice.*

I'm sure they're a lot of other ways to say someone's singing voice is good. How do you restate the above sentence? I'm looking for any equivalent sentences (Formal/Informal/Slang).

Comment: Might be a better fit for [Writers](http://writers.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some similes: she may sing…

- **…like an angel**
- **…like a bird**
- **…like a lark**
- **…like a nightingale**

Comment: It sounds more romantic!

Answer (score 2):

One (very informal) equivalent: "Nice pipes!"

Comment: Is it related to panpipes?

Comment: I don't really know; I first heard it in connection with a church choir, so I've always associated it with organ pipes.  But I really don't know the derivation.

Comment: Pipes,Chords,Vocal Chords..get the connection now?:)

Comment: @abhiii5459 - Breath and voice flow through structures that resemble pipes, so that wasn't really a mystery to me.  Exactly _what kind_ of pipes the voice is being compared to - that's the part I don't know.  Panpipes and organ pipes both seem reasonable to me; sewer pipes somewhat less so (although whenever our neighbors flush their toilet, there is a lovely resonance.)  :)

Comment: Personally, I think this refers more to vocal volume than quality.

Answer (score 2):

A few words can be offered to help construct this sentence that are themselves pleasing to hear:

- **[melodious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/melodious)**
- **[euphonious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/euphonious)**
- **[symphonious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/symphonious)**
- **[harmonious](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/harmonious)**
- **[mellifluous](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mellifluous)**

Comment: My understanding of the word "mellifluous" comes from my mother, who used it sarcastically to describe our dog's shrill bark...

Answer (score 0):

She sings in a **beautiful Mezzo-soprano**.

[Voice types at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_type)

Specify the type of lovely singing voice instead of just saying it's pretty.
That gives the reader a better picture.